# what is difference between void & other data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

what is the difference between void & other data type irrespective by using in  a creation of Methods because my basic knowledge  are not clear that's why I ask this kind of question I can't understand that when to use void and when other datatypes ?

Answer (score -1):

`void` simply means `nothing`. See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/yah0tteb.aspx):

> When used as the return type for a method, void specifies that the
>   method doesn't return a value. void isn't allowed in the parameter
>   list of a method. A method that takes no parameters and returns no
>   value is declared as follows:
>
> ```
> public void SampleMethod()
> {
>     // Body of the method.
> }
> ```
>
> void is also used in an unsafe context to declare a pointer to an
>   unknown type.
>
> For more information, see Pointer types (C# Programming Guide).
>
> void is an alias for the .NET Framework System.Void type.

Comment: Void return nothing.... like lets say.. if i want to assign a value to different text box which is not involved in any process. Then i will use void...